# Как Вернутся в активность после того, как появилось уведомление. Уведомление не кликабельно, не реагирует на нажатия

Tags: java, android-notification, android-alarm-manager, android-broadcastreceiver, pendingintent

Проблема - не получается вернуться в основную активность после нажатия по полученному уведомлению. Само уведомление не кликабельно.
Уведомление запускается в методе onPause (в фоновом режиме)

Моя основная активность MainActivity, в которой происходит настройка уведомления через PendingIntent и AlarmManager

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NotificationManager notificationManager;

private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 1;

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID";

NotificationPublisher notificationPublisher;

Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createNotificationChannel();
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "LemubitReminderChannel";
        String description = "Channel for Lemubit Reminder";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notifyLemubid", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

}

private void reminderMethod (){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Напоминание о запуске фонового уведомления", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationPublisher.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    long inPauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long ten = 2 * 1000;
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, inPauseTime + ten, pendingIntent);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    reminderMethod();
}
```

}

Широковещательный приемник

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int unicode = 0x1F62D;



    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notifyLemubid")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("текст " + getEmojiByUnicode(unicode))
            .setContentText("текст")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(200, builder.build());

}

public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode){
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationPublisher.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

// попробуйте добавить эти 2 строчки в свой код 
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

UP.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationPublisher.class);
```

я так понял, что `NotificationPublisher` это не Активити, а просто класс.
значит и при нажатии на всплывающие окно ничего не происходит. попробуйте изменить на `MainActivity.class` + 2 строчки выше тоже не забудьте.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Comment: Строчки добавил, не помогло

Comment: @vasyatorkin апнул ответ.

Comment: На этот раз даже уведомление не появляется в статус баре. Мне кажется, что на это влияет код, размещенный в классе NotificationPublisher.